# After password reset, I can't log in with the new password in laravel breeze

Tags: laravel, reset-password

[image]

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=myapppasword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="myemail@gmail.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

In Laravel breeze after the reset, I can't log in with the new password

Comment: If you use php artisan tinker you can give yourself a new password. It's really strange that after a password reset you cannot log in

Comment: Can you confirm in the DB that the pw is changed?

Comment: when i fill in the fields after clicking the button the fields are empty and i stay on the same page

Comment: I didn't use php artisan tinker